# How can I use my constructor variables in another widget?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a search bar where user can search some user . And when they click on a user they get navigated to chat screen. And I wanna displaying the user name of the user. But heres my problem: The widget where I navigate the user "the chatscreen" includes other widgets like one widget for the app bar an other for the body. And I just call this widgets inside the chatscreen.
So heres my question how can I use the variables from the constructor of chatscrren inside the appbar widget? Is something like that possible ?

Heres my widget where I give the chat screen some data:

```
  Widget searchListUserTile({String url, username,fullname, email}) {
    final user = Provider.of<Userforid>(context);
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: (){
        Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>ChatScreendetailpage(username,fullname)));
      },
```

And heres my chatscrren widget where I call app bar widget.

```
class ChatScreendetailpage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String chatWithUsername,username;
  ChatScreendetailpage(this.chatWithUsername, this.username);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(child: Messages()),
            NewMessage(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And heres mine app bar widget :

```
class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {

  //String username;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Build you AppBar widget here

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 16),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 2,
                ),
                CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/5.jpg'),
                  maxRadius: 20,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 12,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                       Here should stay the name....................
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 6,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Icon(
                  Icons.settings,
                  color: Colors.black54,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(56);
}
```

Comment: Its very simple. You can pass variable in ChatScreen like: appBar: CustomAppBar('Chatwithusername', 'Username') and add CustomAppBar(this.chatWithUsername, this.username); in your CustomAppbar.

Comment: Yes thank you that was it . Have a nice my friend !

Comment: Hey Buddy please give my answer upvote and mark it correct answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow below way:

Its very simple. You can pass variable in **ChatScreen** like:

`appBar: CustomAppBar('Chatwithusername', 'Username')` and add `CustomAppBar(this.chatWithUsername, this.username);` in your `CustomAppbar.` –